# What's the benefit of a property with readonly getter?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, properties, readonly

I have seen **readonly** many times (often for members, but also in the context of readonly structs).

But what I've seen the first time is the combination **readonly get** for a property:

```
private double _x;
public double X
{
    readonly get => _x;
    set => _x = value;
}
```

But what does it mean? What exactly is the restriction of specifying a getter readonly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `readonly get` syntax is a [new addition to C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/readonly-instance-members). It signifies that the getter may not modify instance members.

Regular getters *may* modify the instance:

```
public double X
{
    get { _x = 1; return _x; }
}
```

That code is entirely valid; more usefully, a getter could for instance update a cached value. `readonly get` accessors cannot do that, and the compiler will enforce this invariant.

Comment: It's a little weird that this isn't well documented by Microsoft. Even your link leads to the C# 8 proposals page and that links to a GitHub issue that is not yet closed...

Comment: It will prevent the compiler from making a defensive copy of the struct if only readonly members are accessed, which is likely the most important part

Comment: This is mentioned in the readonly documentation, as linked in my answer but you have to read between the lines.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 are there any downsides if you just  make them readonly without using "in" modifier?

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid c# code. Check any compiler will get you:

> The modifier `readonly` is not valid  for this item

That is because the getter and setter are just syntactic sugar for functions.

For classes you are indeed right, that there is no point in a read only getter as there is no point in a read only function. Only variables have a point of being read only and properties only by not providing a setter.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/SPhTR8

For structs, it indicates that the greater does not change the state.

So that makes the following getter illegal:

```
// This will get you a compiler error
readonly get { _z = 7d; return _z; }
```

This is stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly

> In an instance member declaration within a structure type, readonly indicates that an instance member doesn't modify the state of the structure.

Comment: I was sure that I saw this on a Microsoft site. So I searched for it again and found it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/write-safe-efficient-code#declare-readonly-members-when-a-struct-cant-be-immutable

Comment: Check the updated answer and the fiddle. I missed the struct mention in your question.

Comment: I think, I've made the same mistake and tried using it in a class instead of a struct.

Comment: readonly get => myVar, is valid from .net core 3 (c # 8), the effect is the same as putting 'const' in a function c ++ that makes getter.
This is that the variable myVar cannot be modified in the get and offers that security.

Comment: @dgzornoza [English is required for all content on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions)